# Хочу уточнить

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении "Они пьют(,) как лошади" нужна запятая или нет? Тут все-таки сравнение или устойчивый оборот, который не выделяется запятой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такой устойчивый оборот, поэтому запятую можно не ставить. Но хочется сказать, что ни в одном справочнике мы не найдем полный список фразеологизмов с "как". И что же получается? Нашли в справочнике - ставим, а  не нашли -  не ставим? Это я к тому, что наличие-отсутствие запятой в подобных выражениях (то ли фразеологизм, то ли нет?) я бы за ошибку не считала.